# Sum from Two Tables by Joining

Tags: sql, mysql

Let say I have two table with 2 columns :
**Table A** :

| Job | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 50 |

And Table B :

| Job | Sell |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |

And I want result query by joining these two tables, as below :

| Job | Cost | Sell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 400 |
| 2 | 300 | 200 |

I try the query as below and the result not as expected :

```
SELECT A.Job, 
       SUM(A.Cost) AS NCOST,
       SUM(B.Sell) AS NSELL   
FROM TableA A 
JOIN TableB B ON A.Job= B.Job
GROUP BY A.Job;
```

Can anyone help me to correct my query ?

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: the result is from tableA , the rows was sum twice due to duplicate rows

Comment: Here's a little [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-xG7bwRB) to help you understand what is happening in your query.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a join use `UNION ALL` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT Job,
       SUM(Cost) AS Cost,
       SUM(Sell) AS Sell
FROM (
  SELECT Job, Cost, 0 AS Sell FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Job, 0, Sell FROM TableB
) AS t
GROUP BY Job;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate totals separately, then join the two datasets :

```
SELECT c.Job, c.COST, s.Sell
FROM (
  SELECT Job, SUM(Cost) AS COST
  FROM TableA
  GROUP BY Job
) AS c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Job, SUM(Sell) AS Sell
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY Job
) AS s on s.Job = c.Job
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4rL-8NEb)

Comment: i don't know how to express my gratitude, it worked...amazing gurus

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate each table first, so that each Job value appears only once, and then join the two aggregated datasets.

At the moment, as Job appears multiple times in the first table if you just join the two tables you'll get duplicated rows